# How can I authenticate a windows app with AAD B2C without the B2C login pages?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an mvc app that provides both a website and a webapi.  I'm happily authenticating users of the website.  Now I need to allow a windows app to call the web api methods directly.  I don't want the windows app to redirect to a login page.  I need the windows app to hold either a secret key or a username/password.  That way it can authenticate itself automatically.

I'm concerned that it seems b2c cannot handle client credential flow - which I think I want.  Is there a way to silently provide the username and password to B2C?

Comment: For client credentials flow, you can use regular AAD endpoint and get a token for your app. and pass it to the API. But are you sure you dont send ROPC instead?

Comment: So I register my app in AAD and AADB2C?

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD B2C does not implement client credentials or ROPC flows of OAuth2. But ROPC is on Azure AD B2C roadmap.

In your case, if you have multiple users using the Windows Application, then you need ROPC because the token retrieved using that mechanism has user context (achieved via user authentication).

Using client_credentials flow means that your Windows Application needs to keep the secret and will authenticate as application only, without any user context. This is ok for daemon and background processes running in a protected environment, but not for apps that you expect to be used by users.

At this point, your best option will be to redirect to Azure AD B2C login pages. Although it is not the same as native experience, the advantages here are that if as you add more options (e.g. MFA, string and language customization, new login options in the future), your client application will not need to be changed, and all your UIs will get those features.